# How can I win the training missing in Arma II called "MOUT Course" without it ending in "training accident/friendly fire" incident?

Tags: arma-2

I am trying to finish the MOUT course in the ARMA II tutorial, and the game is ending, telling me that friendly fire damage outside the course is not allowed.

All I did was get in the vehicle and drive towards the waypoint. Am I allowed to use the vehicle in completing the MOUT course?

When I sit around by the sargeant who sent me into the MOUT course, he got shot and killed by the "insurgents" (other team) and that also ended the game.  I don't understand what I have to do in order for the screen not to go black and tell me I lost.

I have tried this about 20 times in a row, and it always seems to end in "training accident" even when I don't die.  I've been shot. I've died 100 times. I've been not-shot-at-all-and-still lost.  I don't get it.

(I'm a little frustrated. I didn't expect the first training missing with live fire to take me 2 hours and 100 attempts. ARMA 2 is a one or two bullets and you're dead type game, and so it's scary, and fun, but really hard.)

Comment: So far I've figured out that (a) Run and Gun will get you killed every time, and (b) stick to the walls. But I still haven't beat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that your sergeant is copping fire from the fake insurgents as he should be out of a firing solution.  Try parking the humvee to protect him from that direction.

As for the course, it is a tricky one and requires patience. Remember Arma2 is a military simulation, not a first person shooter so charging in when it's 5 against 1 will get you killed every time.

Move towards the town and slightly to the left so you get a good over-watch position down the main street. Stay prone or crouched and scan for two or three minutes.  There should be a patrol on the far side of town but it's random so stay patient and keep watching.  You want to take at least two of them out before they know where you are. Now you want to flank far left, keeping at least 100m from the town.  You should be able to kill another two while they are focused on the direction you where before which leaves you one more to take out in urban combat. Move in slowly from the known to the unknown and watch your corners.

There are two very important things about this game you need to know if you are to be successful.  Firstly, try to see them before they see you.  Second, suppression is critical. If you are taking fire just open up like crazy in the general direction of the enemy, it keeps their heads down, reduces their accuracy and may even kill them.